# Как посчитать выражение

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Как мне посчитать выражение,которое пользователь вводит с клавиатуры и записывается в строковую переменную?Например есть строка с выражение 2+2*2,как мне подсчитать это?

Comment: Например можно взять и почитать полезные книги по программированию. И начать изучать программирование не с objective-c. И хватит флудить. Алгоритм вам подсказал, вам нужно чтобы за вас написали в-с-е?

Comment: Да не,не так,я просто программирую третий день,я хочу найти самый легкий способ решить эту задачу,я смог сам написать что моя программа решала выраение из 2 чисел,но мне надо что высчитывала большое выражение.Вот не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: if ([str isEqualToString:@"2+2*2"]) NSLog(@"%d",6);
else NSLog(@"Неизвестно");

а если серьезно, ответ в комментарии @CrazyTimon

Comment: дак вот берете....pascal, книгу по нему и учитесь программировать, зачем сразу objective-c. Поучитесь писать простенькие программы...от простого к сложному....

Comment: Я неплохо программирую на C#,просто есть задача и я пытаюсь ее решить,хватит уже указывать что мне делать,просто помогите с вопросом

Comment: НУ а действительно можно ли посчитать выражение в строке без особо сложных алгоритмов с парсингом?Есть ли какие нибудь встроенные методы для этого?

Comment: Чтобы грамотно ответить на Ваш вопрос нужно знать в какой среде программируете?
Если это iOS, консольная программа, под Мас? - все это повлияет на алгоритм решения поставленной перед Вами задачи

Comment: Если вы программируете на c#, зачем и нафига вы полезли с этим в objective-c? Гуглите: c# math regular expression. Вы бы еще на brainfuck попросили программу.

Comment: Потому щас я работаю на Objective

Comment: Программирую на Xcode под IOS.Это указано в метках если что

Comment: Алгоритм решения задачи следующий:
1. Рисуете кнопки на View, кадой кнопке присваиваете Title соответсвующий знаку (цифра или операнд (+-*/)).
2. Определяете глобальную переменную, которая держит результат.
2. Кнопки с цифрами нужно подключить к функции, которая будет переводить цифры-стринги в цифры-цифры
3. Кнопки с операндом идут в функцию, которая тупо спрашивает какой это операнд и делает соответсвующую функцию и обновляет результат.
4. При нажатии на кнопку равно - выводим результат на экран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (void)
{
    NSString *expression = @"2+2*2";
    // 0 - любое число, нужно лишь для представления выражения в верном формате
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                    [expression stringByAppendingString:@" == 0"]];
    NSNumber *result_object = [[predicate leftExpression] expressionValueWithObject: nil 
                                                                     context: nil];
    int result = [result_object intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i", result);
}
```

---

Однако, у этого способа есть некоторые недостатки:

> 1. Не всегда верно обрабатывает подряд идущие операторы возведения в степень (**);
> 2. Из поддерживаемых математических функций только
>
> sum, count, min, max, average, median, mode, stddev, sqrt,
> log, ln, exp, floor, ceiling, abs,
> trunc, random, randomn.

Comment: У меня ругается на строчку
[expression stringByAppendingString:@" == 0"]];
пишет
'expression uddeclared
и на строчку
NSNumber *result = [[predicate leftExpression] expressionValueWithObject: nil 
                                                                     context: nil];
пишет 
'nill' undeclared

Comment: Просто вставьте содержимое функции main() (то, что между '{' и '}') в какой-нибудь метод.

Comment: Не пойму что не нравится?ЧТо делает этот текст?

Comment: Я так и сделал

Comment: Выложите получившийся у вас код куда-нибудь на http://pastebin.com/ и дайте ссылку - посмотрю

Comment: Я не могу выложить,я просто работаю на виртуалке и там инет тормозит и виснет

Comment: МНе надо просто посчитать выражение которое состоит из числе и знаков операций '+','-','*','/'

Answer (score 4):

ТС, Вы изначально неправильно взялись за решение поставленной перед Вами задачи. 
Для начала следует определиться с алгоритмом решения. И уже после этого следует искать способы реализации в object-c. К тому же данная задача не настолько проста, чтобы ее решить за 2 минуты. В общем случае надо строить дерево математического выражения, а затем уже совершать его обход и считать результат. 
Касательно постановки задачи. Она абсолютно безобразно изложена. Непонятно, какие именно операции допустимы, могут ли быть скобки в выражении.
И вдогонку, не следует создавать столько тем по одному вопросу!

Answer (score 1):

Парсишь со строки сначала числа, в массив;  Потом парсишь знаки действий(можно конечно попутно и то  и то, но мне кажется, нагляднее и проще по очереди).

Дальше запускаешь цикл по массиву чисел, и на первую пару чисел берешь первый знак, выполняешь действие, а дальше - берешь результат предыдущей итерации, и выполняешь над ним, и след. числом след. действие...

Примерно так... Только с приоритетом операций так не получится... Если не придумаешь какую ни будь логику...

А вообще, самое правильное рещение, это написать свой собственный компилятор арифметического языка программирования.
Я когда-то писал именно такой на Джаве, но не помню, при помощи какой библиотеки, и не помню, как...

Возможно и на обж. си есть что-то подобное.

Comment: Вот мне надо именно с приоритетом,такую штуку как последовательное выполнение операций я уже сделал

Comment: @metalurgus  
> свой собственный компилятор арифметического языка программирования  
  
Это вы что имеете в виду?

Answer (score 0):

Хмм, я не знаком с objC и iOS , но кажется самый простой способ это записать эту строку в текстовый файл и отдать на вычисление интерпретатору - в iOS водится интерпретатор например basic или javascript?

Comment: А как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Сохраню здесь ссылки по данному вопросу:

1. [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser)
2. [GCExpressionParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm)